# How to shape or mask custom carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have carousel.psd for our project and there is a special shape on the carousel how can i do that in css or js ? I'm talking about red shape on the carousel? is there any example?

[image]

```js
// Carousel Auto-Cycle
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 6000
  })
});
```

```css
html {
  font-size: 100% !important;
}


/* Link */

a,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 1;
}

a:hover {
  zoom: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  opacity: 0.6;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Remove Firefox selection dot */

a,
a:focus,
a:active,
a:hover,
object,
embed {
  outline: none !important;
}

:-moz-any-link:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}

:focus {
  outline: 0;
}


/* Remove Firefox Dropdown selection dot */

select:-moz-focusring {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}


/* Image */

a img {
  border: none;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}


/* max-width:100% causes IE8 bug */

div {
  word-break: break-all;
}


/* Main 
------------------------------------------------ */

body {
  background: #333956;
  padding: 0px;
}


/* Carousel Fading slide */

.carousel-fade .item {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.carousel-fade .active.left,
.carousel-fade .active.right {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 3;
}

.carousel-fade .next,
.carousel-fade .prev {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Carousel Control */

.carousel-control {
  top: 43%;
  font-size: 48px;
}


/* Animation */

.control-box,
a.carousel-control,
.carousel-indicators li {
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 250ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 250ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 250ms ease;
  transition: all 250ms ease;
  /* hardware acceleration will cause Bootstrap carousel controlbox margin error in webkit browsers */
  /* Assigning animation to indicator li will make slides flicker */
}


/* Removing BS background */

.carousel .control-box {
  opacity: 0;
}

a.carousel-control.left {
  left: 0;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
}

a.carousel-control.right {
  right: 0;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
}


/* Hover animation */

.carousel:hover .control-box {
  opacity: 1;
}

.carousel:hover a.carousel-control.left {
  left: 15px;
}

.carousel:hover a.carousel-control.right {
  right: 15px;
}


/* Carouse Indicator */

.carousel-indicators li.active,
.carousel-indicators li {
  border: 0;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  background: #666;
  margin: 0 3px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
}

.carousel-indicators li.active {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<section class="main-slider">


  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">



    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">


      <!-- Slide 1 : Active -->
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/carousel/img/carousel1.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Slide 1</h3>
          <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- /.carousel-caption -->
      </div>
      <!-- /Slide1 -->


      <!-- Slide 2 -->
      <div class="item ">
        <img src="https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/carousel/img/carousel1.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Slide 2</h3>
          <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- /.carousel-caption -->
      </div>
      <!-- /Slide2 -->

    </div>
    <!-- /Wrapper for slides .carousel-inner -->



    <!-- Controls -->
    <div class="control-box">
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.control-box -->


  </div>
  <!-- /#myCarousel -->


</section>
<!-- /.main-slider.container -->



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[See on CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aPwpzR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this type of shape using CSS or you can use an image of this shape and put it on top of the slider by positioning it absolutely.

Here I have used 'after'property of main-slider you can use div or image instead

```js
// Carousel Auto-Cycle
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 6000
    })
  });
```

```css
/* Global 
------------------------------------------------ */
@charset "utf-8";
html { font-size: 100% !important; }

/* Link */
a, a:focus { text-decoration: none; opacity: 1; }
a:hover { zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity=60); opacity: 0.6; text-decoration: none; }

/* Remove Firefox selection dot */
a, a:focus, a:active, a:hover, object, embed { outline: none !important; }
:-moz-any-link:focus { outline: none; }
input::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; }
:focus { outline: 0; }

/* Remove Firefox Dropdown selection dot */
select:-moz-focusring { color: transparent; text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000; }

/* Image */
a img { border: none; }
img { width: 100%; height:auto; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; } /* max-width:100% causes IE8 bug */

div { word-break: break-all; }



/* Main 
------------------------------------------------ */
body {
  background: #333956;
  padding: 0px;
}  



/* Carousel Fading slide */
.carousel-fade .item {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.carousel-fade .active.left,
.carousel-fade .active.right {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-control { z-index: 3; }
.carousel-fade .next,
.carousel-fade .prev {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}



/* Carousel Control */
.carousel-control {
  top: 43%;
  font-size: 48px;
  } 

  /* Animation */
  .control-box, a.carousel-control, .carousel-indicators li {
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 250ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 250ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 250ms ease;
    transition: all 250ms ease;   
    /* hardware acceleration will cause Bootstrap carousel controlbox margin error in webkit browsers */
    /* Assigning animation to indicator li will make slides flicker */
   } 

  /* Removing BS background */
  .carousel .control-box { opacity: 0; }
  a.carousel-control.left  { left: 0; background: none; border: 0;}
  a.carousel-control.right { right: 0; background: none; border: 0;}

  /* Hover animation */
  .carousel:hover .control-box { opacity: 1; }
  .carousel:hover a.carousel-control.left { left: 15px; }
  .carousel:hover a.carousel-control.right { right: 15px; }    



/* Carouse Indicator */
.carousel-indicators li.active,
.carousel-indicators li {
  border: 0;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  background: #666;
  margin: 0 3px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
}

.carousel-indicators li.active {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
.main-slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
section.main-slider:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    /* top: 50%; */
    left: 0;
    bottom: -73%;
    width: 180%;
    height: 120%;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<section class="main-slider">


  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">




    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">


      <!-- Slide 1 : Active -->
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://demo.averta.net/themes/lotus/agency/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/slider9.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Slide 1</h3>
          <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</p>
        </div><!-- /.carousel-caption -->
      </div><!-- /Slide1 -->


      <!-- Slide 2 -->
      <div class="item ">
        <img src="http://demo.averta.net/themes/lotus/agency/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/slider9.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Slide 2</h3>
          <p>Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</p>
        </div><!-- /.carousel-caption -->
      </div><!-- /Slide2 -->


      <!-- Slide 3 -->
      <div class="item ">
        <img src="http://demo.averta.net/themes/lotus/agency/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/slider9.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Slide 3</h3>
          <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.</p>
        </div><!-- /.carousel-caption -->
      </div><!-- /Slide3 -->


      <!-- Slide 4 -->
      <div class="item ">
        <img src="http://demo.averta.net/themes/lotus/agency/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/slider9.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Slide 4</h3>
          <p>Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</p>
        </div><!-- /.carousel-caption -->
      </div><!-- /Slide4 -->


    </div><!-- /Wrapper for slides .carousel-inner -->



    <!-- Controls -->
    <div class="control-box">
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
    </div><!-- /.control-box -->


  </div><!-- /#myCarousel -->


</section><!-- /.main-slider.container -->



<!-- Delete This -->
<footer class="info">
  <a href="http://simonalex.com/">&hearts; Redfrost</a> | <a href="https://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/">Get Bootstrap</a> | <a href="https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/">Get Font Awesome</a> | <a href="http://placehold.it/">Get Placeholder</a>

  <p>Bootstrap 3.0 style Carousel mod</p>
</footer>
```